# Based on Button Press in Userform2, data in TextBoxTotal should populate in worksheet MasterList column H in appropriate row

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have tried using code and error handling with step message boxes.  It all works until it tries to populate the amount in TextBoxTotal on UserForm2.  It populates $0.00 regardless of what is in the textbox.  Here is the code, can anyone see where the problem lies?

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox "Button Clicked!" ' Debugging message to check if the button click event is triggered
    
    ' Check if an item is selected in ListBox1
    If ListBox1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
        ' Get the selected item's value from ListBox1
        Dim selectedValue As Variant
        selectedValue = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
        
        MsgBox "Selected Value: " & selectedValue ' Debugging message to display selected value
        
        ' Get the total amount from TextBoxTotal
        Dim totalAmount As Double
        totalAmount = CDbl(Val(TextBoxTotal.Value))
        
        ' Debugging message to display TextBoxTotal Value
        MsgBox "TextBoxTotal Value: " & TextBoxTotal.Value
        
        ' Find the row in MasterList where the selected value is located
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterList") ' Change to the correct sheet name
        
        Dim foundCell As Range
        Set foundCell = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:=selectedValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        ' Debugging message to display address of found cell
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Found Cell Address: " & foundCell.Address
        End If
        
        ' If the selected value is found, update the corresponding cell in column H
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            ws.Cells(foundCell.Row, "H").Value = totalAmount
            
            ' Copy the value from TextBoxTotal and paste it into the same cell
            ws.Cells(foundCell.Row, "H").Value = totalAmount
        End If
    Else
        ' Display a message if no address is selected
        MsgBox "No Address Selected", vbExclamation, "Selection Error"
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    UpdateTextBoxTotal
    TextBoxAmountValue = CDbl(Val(TextBox2.Value))
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Initialize your UserForm here
    ' Set the default value for the spin wheel's counter
    TextBoxCounter.Value = 1
    ' Update TextBoxTotal based on the counter value
    UpdateTextBoxTotal
    
    ' Populate ListBox1 from the MasterList sheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterList") ' Change to the correct sheet name
    
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("B2:B143") ' Change the range as needed
    
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In dataRange
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    ' Update the counter TextBox with the selected value from the SpinButton
    TextBoxCounter.Value = SpinButton1.Value
    ' Update TextBoxTotal based on the counter value
    UpdateTextBoxTotal
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateTextBoxTotal()
    ' Get the counter value from the TextBox
    Dim counterValue As Integer
    counterValue = Val(TextBoxCounter.Value)
    
    ' Get the additional amount from TextBox2
    Dim additionalAmountTextbox As Double
    additionalAmountTextbox = Val(TextBox2.Value)
    
    ' Calculate the base value based on counter value
    Dim baseValue As Double
    baseValue = counterValue * 10
    
    ' Calculate the additional amount based on CheckBox1
    Dim additionalAmount1 As Double
    If CheckBox1.Value Then
        additionalAmount1 = 45
    Else
        additionalAmount1 = 0
    End If
    
    ' Calculate the additional amount based on CheckBox2
    Dim additionalAmount2 As Double
    If CheckBox2.Value Then
        additionalAmount2 = 800
    Else
        additionalAmount2 = 0
    End If
    
    ' Calculate the total value
    Dim totalValue As Double
    totalValue = baseValue + additionalAmount1 + additionalAmount2 + TextBoxAmountValue + additionalAmountTextbox
    
    ' Add the formatted total value to TextBoxTotal
    TextBoxTotal.Value = Format(totalValue, "$#,##0.00")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxCounter_Change()
    UpdateTextBoxTotal
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    UpdateTextBoxTotal
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    UpdateTextBoxTotal
End Sub
```

Please help me out here, everything works except this function.

Ken

I tried the code referenced above and it actually works except that it posts a 0 instead of the amount in the referenced textbox

Comment: Adding `debug.print baseValue, additionalAmount1, additionalAmount2, TextBoxAmountValue, additionalAmountTextbox` at the end of `UpdateTextBoxTotal()`, you could check the value of each part in VBE immediate window. btw, `TextBoxAmountValue` is used in `UpdateTextBoxTotal()`, but there isn't any code line to assign value for it. Is it a _module-level_ variable?